# Divergence therom in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

So I'm trying do a divergence therom problem and I cant get the right answer.

The question is this:

Integrate the Triple Integral $$\iiint(\nabla\cdot V)dv$$ over the region $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 25$ where $$F=(x^2+y^2+z^2)(xi+jy+zk)$$ where $i$, $j$, and $k$ are unit vectors in the $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions.

the answer is supposed to be $100\pi$, or as it says in the book $4\pi(5^2)$ but i keep getting $3125\pi$...

what im doing is solving the divergence, which I get to be $5(x^2+y^2+z^2)$, i then switch it to polar coordinates so the divergence becomes $5p^2$, and then i integrate over the sphere, where $\theta$ is from $0$ to $2\pi$, $\phi$ is from $0$ to $\pi$, and $P$ is from $0$ to $5$, the integrand i get looks like

$$\iiint P^2(P^2\sin\phi)dpd\phi d\theta$$

, and i get a completely wrong answer!
HELP!

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Putting your question into properly formatted MathJax notation will help get it more attention. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a nice reference.

Comment: Given the undefined variables $V,p,P$ the question as stated doesn't make much sense to me. Please be precise! From the context, I presume that $p=P$ is the radius in spherical coordinates, but what is $V$ ? Is it meant to be $F$ ? And why integrate a spherical symmetric problem with full spherical coordinates? Aren't $\phi$ and $\theta$ redundant here?

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's assume that what you mean is the following.

Integrate the Triple Integral $$\iiint(\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{F})\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
over the region $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 25$ [ i.e. a sphere with radius r = 5 ] where $$\vec{F}=(x^2+y^2+z^2)
(x\,\vec{i}+y\,\vec{j}+z\,\vec{k})$$ where $\vec{i}$, $\vec{j}$, and $\vec{k}$
are the unit vectors in the $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions.

Starting with this, your derivation of the divergence is correct:
$$
(\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{F}) = 5(x^2+y^2+z^2) = 5\,r^2
$$
Integrate this over the volume of the sphere, while avoiding unnecessary
operations:
$$
  \int_0^5 5\,r^2\,4\pi r^2 \, dr = 4\pi\left[ \frac{5\,r^5}{5} \right]_0^5 =
  \pi\,12500 \ne 3125\,\pi
$$
Apart from this, you don't need to determine the divergence at all, because
with Gauss' divergence theorem the inner product of the force $\vec{F}$ with the normal
$\vec{n}$ on the surface of the sphere can be integrated over this surface,
which is much easier, because it is everywhere the same:
$$
  (\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}) \times 4\pi 5^2 = 5^2.5
\times4\pi5^2 = \pi\,12500
$$
**Reverse engineering.**
Suppose that the textbook's answer is right and one of
the assumptions in the question is wrong. I take the force as suspect. Let's define instead, with an unknown power $\,p\,$ law: $$
\vec{F}=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^p\,(x\vec{i}+y\vec{j}+z\vec{k})
$$
Then 
$$
  (\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}) \times 4\pi 5^2 = 4 \pi\,5^{2p+3} 
  = \pi\,100 = 4\pi\, 5^2
$$
From which we conclude that $2p+3 = 2$, hence $p = -1/2$ . So the force must
have been:
$$
\vec{F}=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1/2}(x\vec{i}+y\vec{j}+z\vec{k}) =
         \frac{x}{r}\vec{i}+\frac{y}{r}\vec{j}+\frac{z}{r}\vec{k}
$$